# What is the best way of testing web service gateway?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

I am very new to web service  world. Here is the my problem:
I have a set of servers running in UNIX and a gateway(running in tomcat) which uses some wsdl files. The gateway converts the soap request from external client into the api transaction which is server understandable format. The gateway returns back the soap reply. Could you tell me how to test the whole gateway? The external client we haven't developed till now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) for that. It is very fast and easy to use.

Comment: IMO, this is the way to go.  You are simulating a SOAP client, so SoapUI is the proper tool to use.  And it can also perform the load/performance testing as you get past the functional testing.

Comment: @ChrisThornton "this is the way to go" -> not for us running and developping 100+ webservices, we use TDD and CI. Also when testing performance aspects with SOAP UI remember it caches entire requests and has to do an additional Marshalling/ Unmarshalling representing performance aspects of the client only.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have (J)Unit tests for your gateways methods that map the incoming SOAP Requests to a certain structure/ data model and vis a verse.

If said methods on the gateway expect the object representation of the SOAP Message think about the possibility to have the payloads of the SOAP Requests beeing unmarshalled by them and can be delivered to your method. Of course you will have to define the expected outcome per testcase/ request.

Beside the Unit tests of the Gateways methods i would want to have some integration tests that are able to test the entire gateway as a blackbox from outside (e.g. fire requests to a remotely deployed instance of that gateway).

They basicially work the same way with the difference that anything around the mapper-methods will be tested as well and are in the end your "guarantee" the gateway as a blackbox works as expected.

**NOTE:** Input of user @Vikas Gupta is absolutely correct, for manual testing SOAP UI is the way to go. It is up to you whether you go for automated testing and continous integration or manual testing.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the gateway is the client application for your web service, and you want to test the gateway, which is obviously a Java web application.

The recommended way is to write automated test cases using the [JUnit](http://junit.org/) library: you would send sample requests to the gateway (while using your network or business classes) and expect specific results; if the results don't match your expectations, then you would get an error in the JUnit test cases, which have native (nice, graphic) support in the eclipse IDE.